# Change format of value returned in =TODAY()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the today function in an Excel spreadsheet to return the current date. I am the using the value of the cell with the date in it, to create a formula using an indirect concatenate formula to combine the different parts of the formula that I would like to create.

My issue that I keep receiving a #REF! due to the =TODAY() function returning the date a 6 digit number i.e. 41819 instead of the date format 29/06/1014.

Is it possible to make the indirect concatenate or =TODAY() to change the format of the date when it is returned?

**Edited**

Here is the formula that returns using the indirect concatenate.

=Dump(GoogleAnalytics("ga:78770227", "ga:visits"," 41819","41789", "","", "", "", 500, FALSE, FALSE))

Instead it should appear like.

=Dump(GoogleAnalytics("ga:78770227", "ga:visits"," 29/06/2014","30/05/2014", "","", "", "", 500, FALSE, FALSE))

Comment: **Post your formula that uses =TODAY()**

Comment: Date formatted cells are using underlying decimals with Integer part representing Date and decimal part representing time since midnight. Rgds,

Answer (score 6):

Date formatted cells are using underlying decimals with Integer part representing Date and decimal part representing time since midnight. For example, '6/30/2014' corresponds to underlying numeric representation of 41820; as per you example, 41819 corresponds to 6/29/2014 (I guess 6/29/1014 is just a typo in your post). For added clarity, you can enter the number 41820 in any cell and then apply Date format to the cell: it will display 6/30/2014.

In order to convert integer number to Date use Excel formula shown below (enter, for example, 41820 in cell A1 and the formula in cell A2 (to get 06/30/2014):

```
=TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Or, you can enter the formula in `=TODAY()` in cell A1 and get the result in cell A2.

Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the combination of both `TEXT()` and `TODAY()`.
Something like this :

```
=Dump(GoogleAnalytics("ga:78770227", "ga:visits", TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy"), TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy"), "", "", "", "", 500, FALSE, FALSE))
```

Comment: You need to format the output of TODAY() in order to get your desired output. TEXT() can help you format the output if you are using it correctly. Example :

Comment: =TODAY() will return you numbers such as 41820 =TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy") will format the content of TODAY() and will return 17/10/2018